# C# List<> Order by/Group by/Remove

Tags: c#, list

Phew where do I begin...
OK, I have a list that I have to ,,cut up'' into smaller list depending on two properties. When I have finished working with the small list I want it's items removed from the original list :)

f.ex. I have a List<> CustomerProducts, that contains two values CustomerID and ProductID. I begin by ordering the list:

> `var orderedList = CustomerProducts.OrderBy( c => c.CustomerID).ThenBy( c => c.ProductID)ToList( );`

Assume the ordereded list now looks like this:

> CustomerID = 1,    ProductID  = 61
>   CustomerID= 1,    ProductID  = 61
>   CustomerID= 1,    ProductID  = 87
>   CustomerID= 2,    ProductID  = 81
>   CustomerID= 2,    ProductID  = 53

Now I want a new list that contains only the first two items in the list (because they have the same CustomerID and ProductID), and remove these two items from the orderedList, and then continue doing the same to the rest ... while the orderedList is not empty.

somehting like...

> while(orderedList.Count > 0)
>   {
>   //create new list that has the same values...
>   //do some work on the new list
>   //remove the new list from the orderedList
>   //continue...
>   }

Any ideas of a smart solution for this?? smart meaning short code and pretty ofcourse :)

Comment: Just to make sure you get an answer that solves your porblem -- do you really need to maintain that progressively smaller ordered list (which is potentially at least slightly expensive), or do you just need to process the items in groups of matching customerid/productid in order?  The former requires constantly constructing new lists (or removing from the beginning, both relatively expensive operations), while the latter can use a rather straight-forward grouping operation.

Comment: I agree with Jonathan's comment. It sounds like you have an idea in your head of how to solve the problem but are having trouble making it happen. Instead of telling us about the hammer you are trying to use, tell us about the house you are building; the hammer might be the wrong tool for the plumbing. Can you characterize the problem by the business operations you're performing, and not by the implementation details of your proposed mutable-list-based solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var groupedList = orderedList
  .GroupBy(c => new {c.CustomerId, c.ProductId})
  .OrderBy(g => g.Key.CustomerId)
  .ThenBy(g => g.Key.ProductId)
  .ToList();

foreach(var group in groupedList)
{
  List<CustomerProduct> cps = group.ToList();
  //do some work with this customer products

  //no need to do inefficient list removal - just move on to next group.
}
```